# Copy the content by matching the XML tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to copy all the content of a XML by matching a specific node and add a SOAP envelope for each repeating 'postItemCost' node.

Source XML:

```
    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>0.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>0.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>0.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>2201</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322979</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>

    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>0.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>0.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>0.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>1101</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322979</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>

    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>1000.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>1000.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>1000.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>1101</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322984</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>
  </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Expected Output -

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
  <ns0:Message1>

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>0.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>0.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>0.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>2201</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322979</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>0.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>0.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>0.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>1101</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322979</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
      <ItemInvCostReqList>
        <ItemInvCostRequest>
          <invcost>
            <avgcost>1000.00</avgcost>
            <lastcost>1000.00</lastcost>
            <stdcost>1000.00</stdcost>
          </invcost>
          <location>1101</location>
        </ItemInvCostRequest>
        <itemnum>9322984</itemnum>
      </ItemInvCostReqList>
    </ns1:postItemCost>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <xsl:template match="Message//Message1//postInvCostRequest">
          <xsl:copy-of select="/postInvCostRequest"/>
        </xsl:template>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to add the SOAP envelope for every repeating 'postItemCost' node.
So, could you please help me with the XSLT code that could help me achieve the expected output.

Comment: You cannot have a template in another template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge"
xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Messages">
    <xsl:copy>
        <ns0:Message1>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Message1/ns1:postItemCost">
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:Message1>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjVU

---

### Added:

As stated in the comments, you cannot control where a namespace declaration will appear. The following trick will work with *some* processors and force the `xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/"` declaration to appear on the  `ns1:postItemCost` elements - but it cannot be guaranteed to work with every processor or serializing component of your processing chain:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge"
xmlns:ns3="http://items.test.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns3">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Messages">
    <xsl:copy>
        <ns0:Message1>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Message1/ns3:postItemCost">
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:Message1>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do I change if I have to send the 'ns1' namespace as a part of 'postItemCost' tag as below .
<ns1:postItemCost xmlns:ns1="http://items.test.com/">

Comment: Nothing. The namespace is already declared in an ancestor element and inherited from there.

Comment: Thank you for the help michael, however my messages splits for each 'postItemcost' node hence I want the namespace with each node and not with the ancestor. hence it fails in the target system.

Comment: Then the problem is with your splitting method, not with the output of the XSL transformation. In general, you cannot control where a namespace declaration will appear - that's decided by your XSLT processor (or the serializing component of your processing chain). You could try trick it as shown here: http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjVU/1 but it's not guaranteed to work with every processor.

Comment: Thank you michael ! I guessed so. But the link you provided does not work.

Comment: See the addition to my post.